# Undefined References After Linking Against Static Library

Tags: linux, linker, g++, static-libraries, xdotool

I wrote a simple program to test if xdotool can fulfill my requirements. (Well, not really. My first step is to make sure if I can make calls into the xdotool library.)

```
#include <xdo.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << xdo_version() << endl;
    xdo_new(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile this with `g++ -o a main.cpp libxdo.a -lXtst -lX11 -lXinerama -I ../test/xdotool-2.20110530.1`, I get the following error message:

```
/tmp/ccW95RQx.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `xdo_version()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `xdo_new(char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sendkey] Error 1
```

I didn't use the development packages from apt-get install because it installs a dynamic library. So, I did a apt-get source and built the library myself. I verified that xdo_version and xdo_new are defined functions in the static library by performing the following commands:

```
$ nm libxdo.a | grep xdo_version
00000000000002b0 T xdo_version
$ nm libxdo.a | grep xdo_new
0000000000004070 T xdo_new
0000000000003c90 T xdo_new_with_opened_display
```

If I am not mistaken, the `T` besides the symbol's name means that the function is defined.

In conclusion, I'm trying to get the above C++ snippet to compile successfully and statically linking against xdotool but encountered some errors as stated above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint: if the linker shows the signature of a function, then it knows the signature of that function.** What does this mean? It means that it has been somehow encoded in the function name at compilation time, i. e. you are the victim of C++ [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).

It seems that the `xdo.h` header doesn't contain safeguards for the case when the C code is compiled as C++. Declare the functions as `extern "C"` manually for yourself, then recompile, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some guidance in using dynamic library on g++, from coding till running.

**Application code** main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int funct(const int in);

int main(int argc, char** args){

    cout << "test message " << funct(5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Function code** libtest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int funct(const int in){
    return in*in;
}
```

**Building .so file** *libtest.so*

```
g++ -fPIC -c libtest.cpp
g++ -shared -o libtest.so libtest.o
```

**Building application** *main*

```
g++ -L. main.cpp -o main -ltest
```

**Running application**
set environmental variable

@bash:
  *export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH*

@tcsh:
  *setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH :$LD_LIBRARY_PATH*

Run it!!!

```
./main
test message 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell the compiler you are including a C library when you include it:

```
extern "C" {
#include <xdo.h>
}
```